# Jquery show text on hover - Looped Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, hover

I am needing to show text for an icon when it is hovered on. The issue is the icons are displaying via a loop. Meaning I have more than one icon with the same name. I'm sure I need to use "this" somehow to only show text next to the icon that is hovered on. However so far I have failed to do so.

My basic code so far. How would I change the code to show text depending on which icon is being hovered on?

```
$(".material-icons").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
         console.log('Show Name for this Icon')
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
         console.log('Hide Name for this Icon')
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Here is the loop that's being used to show the icons.

```
   <li id='topSection' class="list-group-item active">Amenities </li>
             <li id="amnetiesBox" class="list-group-item">
              <% for(var i=0; i<rentals.amenities.length; i++){ %>
              <i class="material-icons"><%=rentals.amenities[i]%></i>
               <% } %>
            </li>
              </li>
```

An example of the icons being selected:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="amenities" value="personal_video"><span>TV</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="amenities" value="call"><span>Phone</span>
```

Comment: Please add the html near your icons including the text you want displayed.

Comment: Try using `$('.material-icons').on('hover', function() { var text = $(this).data('text'); }` You must have written your icon html like this `<img data-text="The text you want to display" src="">`

Comment: The text needs to be attached to the icon somehow, either as @Abolarinstephen has indicated (in a data- attribute) or a hidden element somewhere near the icon (as XYZ has assumed in his answer).

Comment: You can add the text using the data attribute to the `i` element like this `<i class="material-icons" data-text="icon 1"><%=rentals.amenities[i]%></i>`. Your js would be like $('.material-icons').on('hover', function() { var text = $(this).data('text'); alert('text') }

Comment: @James - How would I add that to to my loop? Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a somewhat simple solution that works. The problem with the other suggestions is that I cant add spans per icon because of the loop (as far as I know.)

I went with this:

```
  $(".material-icons").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
    var text = $(this).text();

    if (text === 'wifi'){
        text = 'Local Wifi'
    }

    if (text === 'local_laundry_service'){
        text = 'Laundry on site'
    }

      $(".showName").show()
      $(".showName").html(text)
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
         $(".showName").hide()
        }
    });
```

So what it's doing is finding the icons name first and if the icon name is "local_laundry_service" etc I'm updating the text to say simply Laundry on site. Obviously you have to do this for each icon that might be used. Not very dry code but I'm not sure how else to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` and display the text related to that target element

```js
$(".material-icons").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).next("span").show()
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
           $(this).next("span").hide()
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="material-icons" ><span>Hover </span></div> <span style="display:none">first</span>
<div class="material-icons" ><span>Hover</span></div> <span style="display:none">second</span>
<div class="material-icons" ><span>Hover</span></div> <span style="display:none">third</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the strategy but the problem with this is I am unable to have a "first, second, third" span right? How would I add that to my loop?